# underscore.js _.where for string and objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, underscore.js

I want to check if a string can be found in a list of objects.

`this.props.value` has a string "apple, peach" and `this.state.list` is a list of object, where each object has a key-value pair. I want to see if "apple, peach" is found in `this.state.list.name`.

From the documentation on Underscore.js: `_.where(list, properties)` and I don't think I can input a string as `list`. How can I check if a string is found in a list of objects?

```
render() {
    fruits = this.props.value # "apple, peach"
    newFruits = _.where(this.props.value, this.state.list) # I want to see if "apple, peach" is found in the list of fruits in state, and if so, re-assign those values into newFruits

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{newFruits}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Any code you have been working with that you can show?

Comment: @MikeBrant it's been edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you want.  If you want a list of objects (key value pair) that shows up in the list, you probably should do the following:

```
newFruits = _.filter(this.state.list, o => _.contains(this.props.value, o.name))
```

Otherwise, if you just want a list of the fruits, you can do the following:

```
newFruits = _.intersect(this.props.value, _.pluck(this.state.list, 'name'))
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't specify clearly enough. I needed back a list of strings, and your second approach was simple and elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

`var newFruits=_.find(this.state.list, function (fruits) {return fruits === this.props.value })?fruits:"";`

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach is to create an array of search terms and filter your list based on finding the item name within the search terms. See https://jsfiddle.net/92xore2x/

```
var fruits = 'apple, peach';
var list = [
    {name: 'apple', id: 0},
    {name: 'orange', id: 1},
    {name: 'peach', id: 2},
    {name: 'plum', id: 3}
];

var fruitsArray = fruits.split(',').map(function(f) { return f.trim(); });

var results = _.filter(list, function(item) {
    return _.contains(fruitsArray, item.name);
});
```